# Varnish: caching even if certain cookies are present in request or response header

Tags: caching, web-applications, varnish

I have a web application where content is dynamic for non signed in users, it is ok to serve stale content for tuned timeout for annonymous users, the way I identify if user is anonymous or logged in is via presence of `cookie A`

I have multiple cookies in web apps, for example: A, B, c

- `A` is only present for logged in users
- `B` & `C` are always present for any user coming back (in request and in all response from backend)

I cannot remove `B` & `C` entirely from application, I want to still be able to cache as long as `A` is not present and still serve all cookies back to user (without removing them from backend response or frontend request)

How can I configure varnish for this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you cache things while still outputting B & C, then every cached object will return same B & C cookies to every user. You really don't want same cookie values served to every user.

Comment: is there a way I can take it out those cookies before cache processing and add them back after cache processing in varnish

Comment: also I can't afford to create session for each request on my app server